# Codename One build error: package java.sql does not exist

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone, eclipse-oxygen

Every build returns the same issues, that the "package java.sql does not exist". I've found that if I comment out a specific bit in the build.xml file the errors don't show and the project builds:

```
<javac destdir="build/tmp" compiler="modern"
    source="1.8"
    target="1.8"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    bootclasspath="lib/CLDC11.jar"
    classpath="lib/CodenameOne.jar:${build.classes.dir}:lib/impl/cls">
    <src path="src"/>
</javac>
```

Is there any future issues that could arise if I leave this commented out? Or maybe there is a way to resolve this issue without commenting it out at all?

Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Build Output:

```
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:3: error: package java.sql does not exist     
[javac] import java.sql.Connection;
[javac]                ^
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:4: error: package java.sql does not exist
[javac] import java.sql.DriverManager;
[javac]                ^
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:5: error: package java.sql does not exist
[javac] import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
[javac]                ^
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:6: error: package java.sql does not exist
[javac] import java.sql.ResultSet;
[javac]                ^
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:7: error: package java.sql does not exist
[javac] import java.sql.SQLException;
[javac]                ^
[javac] C:\PROJECT\GIT\GDG\src\classes\DBHandler.java:8: error: package java.sql does not exist
[javac] import java.sql.Statement;
[javac]                ^
```

Comment: Are you commenting out the entire compile step? That would obviously not constitute a solution to the problem. According to CN1, not every Java package is supported, including SQL "... connecting from a device to a remote database is "impractical"." See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html

Comment: The code I added above is what I've commented out. The program builds fine with no errors, the simulator has no hiccups. I've read that about SQL for CN1, but com.codename1.db.Database package does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

@rbh is correct with [this link](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) which you should read.

Builds in the cloud will stop working for you as we don't support `java.sql`. `java.sql` doesn't make sense for a mobile phone or tablet. You can't connect to a database through the device, it's unreliable and a HUGE security risk. For the local sqlite database you can use our database API which is simpler.

That code in the build.xml file is meant to protect you from using API's we don't support. Notice that Android builds might work since Androids builtin VM has more capabilities but iOS etc. won't work.

Comment: Well that explains why it builds fine when that section is commented out. Thanks. I will look into changing the code to accommodate this.